# SQLAlchemy/pgAdmin: Error: password authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

I'm conducting a study and I need to store some data. I found an open source data scraper and parser online: https://github.com/hicsail/materials

I've followed some instructions (some of which but not all came from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-postgresql-and-pgadmin-using-docker-3a6a8ae918b5)) and
installed Postgres, created a docker-compose.yml file, and created a config file:
[image]

Above is the config file, and this is the .yml file
[image]

I started by going into the pgAdmin folder and running "docker-compose up", after which, this was the result:
[image]

I'm not sure if the "no privileges flag" means anything. Anyway, after this, I opened up a localhost:5050 in my browser and logged into pgAdmin.
[image]

I named the database "materials" as this was what it was supposed to be named.
[image]

Same thing with the username and password; both were named "root". However, when I run the command to parse the data, I'm getting this error:
[image]

I've been stuck on this for a long time now, and I can't seem to find any solution. This is running in a python2.7 conda environment, as per the requirements. These were the other installed libraries (I'm not 100% sure those were the exact versions, but I tried to get them as close as possible).

```
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
requests>=2.20.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9
wheel==0.24.0
```

If I need to clarify anything please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: The log file for PostgreSQL (probably visible in the docker-compose window) should contain a more detailed error message for the authentication failure

Comment: I've updated the last error message. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: No, that is the error sent to the client.  The error sent to the database server log while have more details about the authentication problem.

Comment: What information have you used to log in to pgAdmin?

Comment: @jjanes there was no more errors I believe in that log I believe. nothing would've helped by scrolling up a little bit. AndreFeijo I logged in with admin@admin.com and password root. When creating the db, i used root as the username and root as the password. Could this have something to do with the ports?

Comment: That failure will generate a log entry on the server.  If it doesn't, then your login attempt must be getting directed to a different database server than the one you think it is.

Comment: You should post text as text, not as pictures of text.  Most people are going to be unwilling to retype all your config files just so they can test your docker for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this. I had to go into services, then to postgres, and stop it from running. I then had to kill the port "5432" and run it again.